# SOAPUI Groovy parsing XML response and insert it into mysql database

Tags: mysql, groovy, soapui, xmlslurper

Im a beginner in groovy and trying to parse XML and insert the resultant records into MySQL database
Sample SOAP XML response

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <soap:Body>
          <GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
             <GetCitiesByCountryResult><NewDataSet>
      <Table>
        <Country>British Indian Ocean Territory</Country>
        <City>Diego Garcia</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>India</Country>
        <City>Ahmadabad</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>India</Country>
        <City>Akola</City>
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet></GetCitiesByCountryResult>
          </GetCitiesByCountryResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

SOAPUI GROOVY teststep script

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather', 'root', 'security', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver') 
def response = context.expand( '${GetCitiesByCountry#Response}' )
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response).Body.GetCitiesByCountryResponse.GetCitiesByCountryResult.NewDataSet.Table
//log.info xml
xml.each{ node -> 
    sql.execute("INSERT INTO indcit(country,city) VALUES (?,?)" ,[node.Country, node.City])
    //sql.execute("INSERT INTO indcit(country,city) VALUES (${node.Country},${node.City})")
    //log.info node.Country
    //log.info node.City
    }
```

When tried both sql.execute line throws the same below error of java.sql.SQLException:Invalid argument value: java.io.NOTSerializableException

Error log

```
Thu Mar 03 01:16:36 IST 2016:ERROR:java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:3415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:3066)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.setObject(Sql.java:3655)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.setParameters(Sql.java:3620)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.getPreparedStatement(Sql.java:3881)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.getPreparedStatement(Sql.java:3928)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.execute(Sql.java:2287)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script62$_run_closure1.doCall(Script62.groovy:7)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1297)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at Script62.run(Script62.groovy:6)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you first register the JDBC? https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#10-Use-a-JDBC-Driver-from-inside-a-groovy-script

Comment: Thanks for highlighting

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `text()` on your nodes, ie:

```
sql.execute("INSERT INTO indcit(country,city) VALUES (?,?)" ,[node.Country.text(), node.City.text()])
```